# How can I find the size of multiple folders?

Tags: macos, finder

When I highlight several folders in Finder and do a get info, I get an info window for each folder.  Is there a way to get a single window showing size of all folders highlighted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open a finder window and set the view to list view.
Press command-J and select "calculate all sizes" then click "use as standard".

Now folder sizes will show in your finder.
I don't think it is possible to show sizes for multiple folders, but this might be a good workaround.

Comment: cmd+alt+i and highlight what you need

Answer (score 40):

<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>alt/option</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> will give you info on multiple highlighed items.

Comment: How is alt done since it is own the option key?

Comment: alt and optn is the same key

Answer (score 9):

There are 3 forms of "Get Info":

1) Standard "`Get Info`" achieved through <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> which can potentially create multiple windows for each item selected.

2) "`Get Summary Info`" achieved through <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> which uses a single window to show combined info about the selection:

[image]

3) "`Inspector`", like @iskra mentioned, achieved through <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>, which is similar to `2)` except that it updates the info dynamically based on your selection.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively

- open Terminal.app
- `cd` to the directory 'above' the ones you need the size for
- `du -sh FOLDER1 FOLDER2` gives sizes in "human readable" format (Use unit suffixes: Byte, Kilobyte, Megabyte, Gigabyte, Terabyte
  and Petabyte.)
- `du -sm FOLDER1 FOLDER2` gives sizes in megabytes
- `du -sg FOLDER1 FOLDER2` gives sizes in Gigabytes

Comment: Or go into terminal, type `du -sm` and drag all the files you want to include in the calculation in there