# Looking for a mac application/plugin that shows file and folder sizes in Finder

Tags: macos

I'm looking for a mac application/plugin that reveals file and folder sizes like the screenshot from the system information browser below. Basically just to allow cleaning HDs and folders a little more easily.

Any recommendations?

TIA

[image]

Comment: Have you dismissed using [Finder, calculate all folder sizes](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/33306/5472) option ?

Answer (score 2):

I use [OmniDiskSweeper](https://www.omnigroup.com/blog/omnidisksweeper-catalina) for doing the exact same thing that you are requesting.

[image: Screenshots of OmniDiskSweeper]

Comment: Hey - just to shout back and say that OmniDiskSweeper was exactly what I was looking for.   I was looking for this, because any free 'duplicate finder' applications I've used tend to offer nothing useful in their free versions. If you have any other recommendations for any other applications helpful when 'cleaning up' harddrives, feel free to share them. Thanks again!